# OpenCV hmm text detection algorithm is not working on simple image

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, text-recognition

I'm trying to write simple program to recognize some simple patterns. It works fine with tesseract, but for some reason it doesn't work with `Hmm`. Here is sample code:

```
std::string image_path = "assets/ubuntu.png";
std::string filename = "assets/OCRHMM_transitions_table.xml";
auto image_source = cv::imread(image_path);
cv::Mat image;
cv::cvtColor(image_source, image, 6);
cv::Mat transition_p;
cv::FileStorage fs(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);
fs["transition_probabilities"] >> transition_p;
fs.release();
cv::Mat emission_p = cv::Mat::eye(62,62,CV_64FC1);
std::string voc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
auto classifier = cv::text::loadOCRHMMClassifierNM("assets/OCRHMM_knn_model_data.xml.gz");
auto ocr = cv::text::OCRHMMDecoder::create(classifier, voc, transition_p, emission_p);

std::string output;
std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes;
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::vector<float> confidences;
ocr.get()->run(image, output, &boxes, &words, &confidences);
std::cout << output;
```

and sample image:

[image]

Expected output: `uBuntu`

Actual output: `m`

What's wrong with this code? I just tried to adopt [demo sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/webcam_demo.cpp#L175).

Here is [OCRHMM_transitions_table.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/OCRHMM_transitions_table.xml) and [OCRHMM_knn_model_data.xml.gz](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/OCRHMM_knn_model_data.xml.gz) which was used (I actually took them from this sample too).

OpenCV version 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Cascade classfier look like not trained enough.Why don't you use another classfier?It detects u half of m

[image]

Comment: Good theory. However, it's not true because it returns `m` for all images I tried till now, for example image with single letter `x` is recognised as `m`. It may be very bad trained model, but I don't believe so beacuse I took it from official example which couldn't be this bad on that easy font.